# How to convert KeyEventArgs.KeyCode to Enum Keys

Tags: c#

Hi im currently searching on how to convert the keycode in the event of Keydown in the KeyEventArgs of a certain control is there a way to do it? i've found a way to convert Keys Enum to Int I want it in the other way..

Comment: KeyCode is [already Keys enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode(v=vs.110).aspx). Am I miss anything?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The title says KeyCode to Keys and the body suggests int to Keys is desired. The KeyCode property is of type Keys. What are you trying to do? Do you just want KeyValue which is an int?

Comment: paste some code what you tried better for our understanding

Comment: i just want to get the enum using its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use casting to get the Enum value of an int, although if you have KeyEventArgs then you already have both (`KeyCode` and `KeyValue`).

```
void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // You can cast a Keys enum to an int 
    // (although you already have the int value in e.KeyValue)
    int keyInt = (int) e.KeyCode;

    // You can cast an int to a Keys enum 
    // (although you already have the enum value in e.KeyCode)
    Keys keyKeys = (Keys)keyInt;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for modifier keys like Alt or Control:
`Keys keyKeys = (Keys)17; //17 = ControlKey
//returns LButton | ShiftKey instead of ControlKey`

Answer (score 1):

If what you are wanting is to take an int and convert it to a Keys Enumeration you can use the [`System.Enum.ToObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Enum.ToObject(v=vs.110).aspx) Method.

```
Keys key = (Keys)System.Enum.ToObject(typeof(Keys), 65 ); //Will be A
```

Though without seeing your code it is very hard to make a determination exactly what you are trying to do.

From above link:

> Converts a specified integer value to an enumeration member.